# Como consertar o erro: "declaration of template parameter 'T' shadows template parameter" em C++?

Tags: c++

Estou tentando fazer um programa de graficos, mas estou tendo um problema...
Meu codigo e esse:

main.cpp:

```
#include "point_2d.h"
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    cge::point_2d p(5, 5);
    p.x = 6;
    std::cout << p.x << " " << p.y << std::endl;
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

point_2d.h:

```
#ifndef POINT_2D_H
#define POINT_2D_H

namespace cge
{

    template<typename T>
    struct basic_point_2d
    {

        typedef T value_type;

        constexpr basic_point_2d() noexcept = default;

        constexpr basic_point_2d(const basic_point_2d&) noexcept = default;

        constexpr basic_point_2d& operator=(const basic_point_2d&) noexcept = default;

        template<typename U>
        constexpr explicit basic_point_2d(const basic_point_2d<U>&) noexcept; //Conversions

        constexpr basic_point_2d(T, T) noexcept; //Constructors

        constexpr bool equal(const basic_point_2d&) const noexcept;

        template<typename T>
        friend constexpr bool operator==(const basic_point_2d<T>&, const basic_point_2d<T>&) noexcept; 

        template<typename T>
        friend constexpr bool operator!=(const basic_point_2d<T>&, const basic_point_2d<T>&) noexcept;


        T x = T();
        T y = T();

    }; //struct basic_point_2d

    typedef basic_point_2d<int> point_2d;
    typedef basic_point_2d<unsigned> upoint_2d;
} //namespace cge 

#endif //POINT_2D_H
```

point_2d.cpp:

```
#include "point_2d.h"

template<typename T>
constexpr cge::basic_point_2d<T>::basic_point_2d(T _X, T _Y) noexcept:
    x(_X), y(_Y)
{
}

template<typename T>
template<typename U>
constexpr cge::basic_point_2d<T>::basic_point_2d(const basic_point_2d<U>& _Right) noexcept:
    x(static_cast<U>(_Right.x)), y(static_cast<U>(_Right.y))
{
}

template<typename T>
constexpr bool cge::basic_point_2d<T>::equal(const basic_point_2d<T>& _Right) const noexcept
{
    return(this->x == _Right.x && this->y == _Right.y);
}

template<typename T>
constexpr bool operator==(const cge::basic_point_2d<T>& _Left, 
    const cge::basic_point_2d<T>& _Right) noexcept
{
    return(_Left.equal(_Right));
}

template<typename T>
constexpr bool operator!=(const cge::basic_point_2d<T>& _Left, 
    const cge::basic_point_2d<T>& _Right) noexcept
{
    return(!(_Left == _Right));
}
```

Meu makefile e assim:

```
test: main.o point_2d.o
    g++ main.o point_2d.o -o test

main.o: main.cpp
    g++ -c main.cpp -std=c++1z 

point_2d.o: point_2d.cpp point_2d.h
    g++ -c point_2d.cpp -std=c++1z
```

e quando eu compilo o programa tenho essas surpresas:

```
In file included from point_2d.cpp:1:
point_2d.h:26:18: error: declaration of template parameter 'T' shadows template
parameter
         template<typename T>
                  ^~~~~~~~
point_2d.h:7:14: note: template parameter 'T' declared here
     template<typename T>
              ^~~~~~~~
point_2d.h:29:18: error: declaration of template parameter 'T' shadows template
parameter
         template<typename T>
                  ^~~~~~~~
point_2d.h:7:14: note: template parameter 'T' declared here
     template<typename T>
              ^~~~~~~~
mingw32-make: *** [makefile:8: point_2d.o] Error 1
```

Procurei muito na internet, mas não consegui achar nenhuma solução satisfatoria para o problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O erro diz que o parâmetro de template dos seus membros tem o mesmo nome que o da classe, assim impedindo o seu uso dentro do membro.

Mude o nome do parâmetro pra livrar-se do erro:

```
template<typename U, typename V>
friend constexpr bool operator==(const basic_point_2d<U>&, const basic_point_2d<V>&) noexcept;
```

Ou remova por completo o template nos membros, que faz mais sentido:

```
friend constexpr bool operator==(const basic_point_2d&, const basic_point_2d&) noexcept;
```

Comment: Quando removi o template dos membros, compilou, mas eu fiquei com 4 warnings.